# Missing photos in photo library on iPhone 6 iOS 8.1

Tags: iphone, photos

I have an iPhone 6, updated to iOS 8.1. Since my storage space is limited, I wanted to transfer all my photos to my Mac and delete them on my iPhone. Once I did that, I looked at the "Usage" tab in Settings. After deleting every single photo, video, and disabling Photostream and iCloud photo sharing, it still says that my photo library is 1.1 GB.

Any ideas how this is possible? Note, I have no single item in the photo library.

Comment: Did you check 'Recently Deleted'?

Comment: Nothing there... iPhoto asked to delete them, and I clicked 'Yes'. Something gone wrong there?

Comment: I don't know the definitive answer, but 'incorrect reporting' comes up often on SE; the 'fix' is often iTunes sync, backup, restore. It seems to be a bit like the old 'switch it off then on again' fix. [use encrypted backups & you get your passwords back afterwards too]

Comment: Hmmm... That's unfortunate. Seems like I have no other option, so I'll just have to do a backup and restore. By the way, passwords are also synced via iCloud right? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I think they are - but I've never trusted iCloud for a restore, I always use iTunes. I'm a bit old-school that way, belt, braces.. rope & tackle ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin I thought I am oldest one here...but now it looks like you are :)

Comment: @Buscar웃 Some days, I feel like calling Lazarus "Son" :P